# How to use cloth simulation without moving the edge position?

Tags: cloth-simulation

I just want to expand the mid-area of my mesh using cloth simulation without moving the position of mesh edge (it is like filling a balloon with Helium). I have tried to use a vertex group but it doesn't work.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should create a vertex group and assign the vertices you want to not move and pin in that group in the `Cloth` `Shape` setting and in the last, just increase the `pressure` and `pressure scale`.
Hope it helps.

Here is the file.

[image]

Comment: it work so well than i expected, thanks for your answer @Muzammil

Comment: @Bahamut77 Glad I could help.